# Is there any other method to handle many 'malloc' failures?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to write a function in C to solve a math problem. In that function, there are several steps, and each step needs to allocate some memory with the size depending on the calculation results in previous steps (so I can't allocate them all at the beginning of the function). The pseudo code looks like:

```
int func(){
    int *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4;
    ...

    p1 = malloc(...);
    if(!p1){
        return -1;            //fail in step 1
    }

    ...
    p2 = malloc(...);
    if(!p2){
        free(p1);
        return -2;            //fail in step 2
    }

    ...
    p3 = malloc(...);
    if(!p3){
        free(p1);
        free(p2);
        return -3;            //fail in step 3
    }

    ...
    p4 = malloc(...);
    if(!p4){
        free(p1);
        free(p2);
        free(p3);            /* I have to write too many "free"s here! */
        return -4;           //fail in step 4
    }

    ...
    free(p1);
    free(p2);
    free(p3);
    free(p4);

    return 0;                //normal exit
}
```

The above way to handle malloc failures is so ugly. Thus, I do it in the following way:

```
int func(){
    int *p1=NULL, *p2=NULL, *p3=NULL, *p4=NULL;
    int retCode=0;
    ...

    /* other "malloc"s and "if" blocks here */

    ...
    p3 = malloc(...);
    if(!p3){
        retCode = -3;            //fail in step 3
        goto FREE_ALL_EXIT;
    }

    ...
    p4 = malloc(...);
    if(!p4){
        retCode = -4;            //fail in step 4
        goto FREE_ALL_EXIT;
    }

    ...
FREE_ALL_EXIT:
    free(p1);
    free(p2);
    free(p3);
    free(p4);

    return retCode;              //normal exit
}
```

Although I believe it's more brief, clear, and beautiful now, my team mate is still strongly against the use of 'goto'. And he suggested the following method:

```
int func(){
    int *p1=NULL, *p2=NULL, *p3=NULL, *p4=NULL;
    int retCode=0;
    ...

    do{

        /* other "malloc"s and "if" blocks here */

        p4 = malloc(...);
        if(!p4){
            retCode = -4;            //fail in step 4
            break;
        }

    ...     
    }while(0);

    free(p1);
    free(p2);
    free(p3);
    free(p4);

    return retCode;              //normal exit
}
```

Hmmm, it seems a way to avoid the use of 'goto', but this way increases indents, which makes the code ugly.

**So my question is,** is there any other method to handle many 'malloc' failures in a good code style? Thank you all.

Comment: "but this way increases indents, which makes the code ugly." - 2 points: excessive indents are bad; you don't have excessive indents. (2) don't use goto when you can write the code perfectly clearly without them.

Comment: Your team mate is wrong.

Comment: well, there are still some indents in the `do{}while(0)` block that I didn't show :)

Comment: The idea that `goto` is always evil is not valid. As long as your sensible in using it, it is a great tool. Plus, by using goto, you say what you mean. IMO, it sure beats the extremely indirect usage of a loop which never actually loops just for that sake of using break instead of goto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your teammate how he would re-write this sort of code:

```
if (!grabResource1()) goto res1failed;
if (!grabResource2()) goto res2failed;
if (!grabResource3()) goto res3failed;

(do stuff)

res3failed:
releaseResource2();
res2failed:
releaseResource1();
res1failed:
return;
```

And ask how he would generalize it to `n` resources.  (Here, "grabbing a resource" could mean locking a mutex, opening a file, allocating memory, etc.  The "free on NULL is OK" hack does not solve everything...)

Here, the alternative to `goto` is to create a chain of nested functions:  Grab a resource, call a function that grabs another resource and calls another function that grabs a resource and calls another function...  When a function fails, its caller can free its resource and return failure, so the releasing happens as the stack unwinds.  But do you really think this is easier to read than the gotos?

(Aside:  C++ has constructors, destructors, and the RAII idiom to handle this sort of thing.  But in C, this is the one case where `goto` is clearly the right answer, IMO.)

Comment: This is the very example I use when defending the (correct) usage of gotos.

Answer (score 7):

`goto` in this case is legitimate. I see no particular advantage to the `do{}while(0)` block as its less obvious what pattern it is following.

Comment: It should be noted that this `goto` pattern is used for the Linux kernel as well.

Comment: I don't like `goto`, but C doesn't have garbage collection or exceptions (you have to check the result of functions yourself), and no try...finally. IMHO, it's the lesser of 2 evils. :-)

Comment: Yes it is great for escaping nested loops and also for going to different error handling "functions" to clear held locks/semaphores and reporting the correct error returns.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there's nothing wrong with goto—this is a perfectly legitimate use of `goto`.  The `do { ... } while(0)` with `break` statements are just gotos in disguise, and it only serves to obfuscate the code.  Gotos are really the best solution in this case.

Another option is to put a wrapper around `malloc` (e.g. call it `xmalloc`) which kills the program if `malloc` fails.  For example:

```
void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *mem = malloc(size);
    if(mem == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory trying to malloc %zu bytes!\n", size);
        abort();
    }
    return mem;
}
```

Then use `xmalloc` everywhere in place of `malloc`, and you no longer need to check the return value, since it will return a valid pointer if it returns at all.  But of course, this is only usable if you want allocation failures to be an *unrecoverable* failure.  If you want to be able to recover, then you really do need to check the result of every allocation (though honestly, you'll probably have another failure very soon after).

Comment: Good idea. But to my problem I do have to check them -- if my function's method cannot solve the math problem, we would like to try another one in the program :)

Comment: +1, but I do cringe every time someone uses the phrase "goto in disguise". Control structures are control structures: nobody calls `while` loops `if` statements in disguise.

Comment: "just gotos in disguise" - it's not *just* `goto` in disguise, since `break` enforces a forward jump, never a backward one. Although that restriction imposes structure beyond that imposed by `goto`, I don't think it has much value here. It's not as if the `FREE_ALL_EXIT` label will in future be moved to the start of the function. Actually, I suppose one could define "goto in disguise" to mean any jump, that is, one could claim that all structured programming is "just" goto and if in disguise, in which case the observation is true but deeply misleading.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with goto in error handling and there's actually no code difference between using a do { ... } while(0); with breaks; instead of goto (since they're both jmp instructions). I would say that seems normal. One thing you could do that is shorter is create an array of int * types and iterate through while calling malloc. If one fails free the ones that are non-null and return an error code. This is the cleanest way I can think of so something like

```
int *arr[4];
unsigned int i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    if (!(arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int))) {
        retCode = -(i + 1); //or w/e error
        break;
    }
if (errorCode)
   for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       if (arr[i])
           free(arr[i]);
       else
           break;
```

or something along those lines (used brain compiler for this so I might be wrong)
Not only does this shorten your code but also avoids goto's (which I don't see anything wrong with) so you and your teammate can both be happy :D

Comment: Thank you but you didn't read my question carefully: I **cannot** allocate all memory in a time because the dependency issue.

Comment: What do you mean in a time? If you know how many you need to allocate you allocate one by one. Once one of them fails you set the errorCode value and free the ones that did allocate and return the errorCode correct?

Comment: oh, sorry, my English is a little poor. 'In a time' I meant is 'in **one** time'. That is to say, I can allocate memory and make arr[0] handle it, but this moment, I still don't know how big memory to allocate for arr[1], arr[2] and arr[3].

Comment: How does that work out? You should know how much memory you want to allocate ahead of time unless you're using the malloced area to find out how much memory to allocate in which case you can keep a variable inside the loop to hold that value I just used sizeof(int) as a placeholder.

Comment: It is exactly the 'unless' situation you've said. The calculation step is complex so I don't want to put it into the `for` block :-)

Comment: What's wrong with putting it in the for block? Also why do you have an int * to a block of memory that is not sizeof(int) or a multiple of sizeof(int)? (dynamic array maybe?)

Comment: I'm confused... maybe I did not explain it clearly? First, the `int*` to the block is a multiple of sizeof(int), and the multiple value relies on the previous calculation of allocated memory contents. Second, the calculation takes about 80 lines in C code, if I put it in the `for` block, it will be hard to read.

Comment: can't you separate that out into another function and save the result? if you have malloc checks + 80 lines of code + malloc checks + 80 lines of code THAT would get hard to read

Comment: Oh, my case is `malloc check + 80-line code + malloc check + 10-line code + malloc check + ...`. They are different. Besides, that 80-line code not only calculates the size of memory, but also intermediate result of the math problem. That's why I didn't put it into another function. This question is short, so I cannot give many details to make buddies here giddy ;-)

Comment: Then I would suggest just using what you wrote although long functions are hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

David Hanson wrote the book *C Interfaces and Implementations: Techniques for Creating Reusable Software*. His Mem interface provides functions that are "similar to those in the standard C library, but they don't accept zero sizes and never return null pointers." The source code includes a production implementation and a checking implementation.

He also implements an Arena interface. The Arena interface releases you from the obligation to call free() for every malloc(). Instead, there's just a single call to free the entire arena.

[CII source code](https://sites.google.com/site/cinterfacesimplementations/)

Answer (score 0):

If an allocation fails, simply assign the error code as normal. conditionalize each malloc like so:

```
if (retCode < 0) malloc...
```

and then at the end of your code, add this:

```
int * p_array[] = { p1, p2, p3, p4};
for (int x = -retCode + 1; x >= 0; x-- )
{ 
    free(p_array[x]);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what your `if` block means. However it seems the program cannot end immediately when an allocation fails, that isn't what I need :-)